# Like a post on Tumblr without following

Tags: tumblr

Do I need to follow someone on Tumblr to be able to "like" a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can always hit the heart at the top of the page or (on dashboard) the post regardless of whetehr or not you're following. Same for reblogging. IIRC, commenting is the only thing you can't do.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't seeing the heart at the top of the page because [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) was blocking it.